# Mini Recorder from RC Heli Parts

Tags: control, cameras, circuit

I had a RC Helicopter (with video,picture, and audio taking capabilities) that recently "died" (unrelated to short circuit). The reciever board short circuted, but the board that sent data to micro-sd card and had camera+mic was fine. I can access the data on the micro-sd card through the circuit, with a USB cable. The reciever board sent data via a 4 wire bundle to the camera board to make it take pictures/record audio. Is there any way to still do this from my computer (from the USB), and turn it into a mini spy camera? (Not remotely, jst through a cable)

I got this heli a while back so I don't have the heli number but the camera board number is `TX6473 R1`, and the reciever board number is `3319B rev.a`

**Reciever Board Image**
[image: Reciever Board Image]
**Camera/Data Board Image**
[image: Camera/Data Board Image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following information:  Manufacturer, part number, and model number for each of the two boards.  If you don't have that info, then main IC numbers plus mfg/pn/mn for the helicopter.

Comment: Thanks for adding the numbers.  Neither google nor google images seem to have anything relevant to the TX6473 camera board but 3319B in google images shows lots of RC helicopters; maybe some of their associated pages will have a pdf manual or other useful info.

Comment: is there any way to send "reciever"data directly to the board from my usb cable? There are a lot of files on the micro sd card (system files i presume).